# R raster plot cropping plotRGB image

Tags: r, image, plot, raster

I have R code as below. 1st `plot()` and 1st `plotRGB()` command work fine. I would like to split the images

in the second block of code `plot()` works but `plotRGB()` fails. How can I make `plotRGB` work in that second case? My end goal is to get the cropped image in original colors

```
 r <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
 r1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
 plot(r)
 plotRGB(r1, interpolate = TRUE)

 plot(r,xlim=c(0,50),ylim=c(0,50),legend=FALSE,axes=FALSE,frame.plot=F)
 plotRGB(r1,xlim=c(0,50),ylim=c(0,50),legend=FALSE,axes=FALSE,frame.plot=F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug, but it easy to work around it via the 'crop' function

```
r1 <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
x <- crop(r1, extent(0,50,0,50))
plotRGB(x)
```

Comment: one more question.  i want to highlight (0,50,0,50) area of my image with red border (no fill)...how could i do that?

Comment: @user2543622 Continuing on with Robert's example, you could just do something like: `plot(extent(c(0,20,0,20)), lwd=2, col="red", add=TRUE)`